# PostgreSQL HA in Kubernetes with already replicated persistent volume

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, high-availability

I want to deploy a highly available PostgreSQL in a K8S cluster. The persistent volumes are leveraging a Ceph cluster that is already configured with replication.

So my only requirement is to achieve replication at service level, not at data level.

I had a look over [stolon](https://github.com/sorintlab/stolon) , [patroni](https://github.com/zalando/patroni) and the "official" [helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql-ha) but as far as I can tell, none of them are supporting my scenario.

Are there any OSS solutions implementing my use case ?

Comment: What do you mean by `replication at service level`? What do you want to `replicate`? Do you want to run multiple instances of PostgresSQL with some of them as standbys?

Comment: Yes, in k8s terminology replicas for a deployment. I just want to avoid replicating the data twice (at storage level and at application level)